# If $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$, then the closure of some $E_n$ contains an interval

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

I'm working on some problems in Carothers' *Real Analysis*. I just started the section on the Baire Category Theorem. Thus far Carothers has given the Baire Category Theorem for $\mathbb{R}$.

> Prove that if $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$, then the closure of some $E_n$ contains an interval. That is, $\operatorname{int}(\overline{E}_n)\neq \emptyset$, for some $n$.

Thoughts/Attempt:

Not really sure where to start on this one, so I'll just state some stuff I know.
The Baire theorem we learned for $\mathbb{R}$ states that the infinite intersection of open dense sets in $\mathbb{R}$ is non-empty, and is in fact dense in $\mathbb{R}$ as well. An interval $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ has limit points $a$ and $b$. A hint would be appreciated to get started. Thank you.

Comment: Consider the sets obtained by taking the complement of the closures of the sets $E_n$.

Comment: The theorem applies to COUNTABLY infinite intersections of open dense sets.  It's easy to find counterexamples if intersections of uncountably many such sets are allowed.  For example $\displaystyle\bigcap_{x\in\mathbb R} (\mathbb R\setminus\{x\})=\varnothing$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbb{R} = \cup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ where int$(\overline{E}) = \emptyset$ for all $n$ then $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets contradicting the Baire Category Theorem.